# Imposible incluir momentjs en Laravel5 con 'laravel-mix'

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, momentjs

Estoy usando `laravel-5` que viene con `webpack` y `laravel-mix`, la idea es usar la librería `datetimepicker` que a la vez usa `momentjs`. El problema es que no consigo incluir la librería de ninguna de las maneras.

He probado todo lo que he podido leer, pero solo una cosa me ha hecho avanzar:

Primero

```
npm install datetimepicker --save-dev
npm install moment --save-dev
```

Luego una de estas dos:

Hacer un `require('../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');` en `resources/assets/js/app.js`

O editar `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js([
  //Plugins
  'node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js',
  'node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Después de ambos casos se ejecuta `npm run dev` o `npm watch`, antes de terminar siempre me sale el siguiente error:

```
WARNING in ./~/moment/min/moment.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in '/proyecto/node_modules/moment/min'
 @ ./~/moment/min/moment.min.js 6:16637-16659
```

En podido leer bastante sobre el tema, y solo he encontrado una manera en la que no aparece el error, lo dicen [aquí.](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3872#issue-217671235).

Aun así, compilando bien y sin dar ningún error, cuando intento ejecutar `console.log(moment().millisecond());` siempre me da el error en consola de: `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

Comentan en [la propia página de `momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/) usar `var moment = require(...)`, que también lo comentan en la [`issue` de `github`](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1435#issue-26100593), pero nada, lo mismo.

¿Alguien que use `datetimepicker` o en su defecto `momentjs` con `Laravel5` sabe como incluir la librería sin errores?

Mi fichero de `resources/assets/js/app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

//var moment = require('moment');
require('../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');
console.log(moment().millisecond());
require('../../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para explircarte voy a suponer que estamos en un proyecto nuevo con laravel, así:

1. Instalamos la versión recomendada de laravel 5.4 que viene con webpack y laravel-mix listos para su uso.

   ```
   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-with-moment
   ```

   donde `project-with-moment`es el nombre de la carpeta que contendrá el proyecto.
2. Ingresando al proyecto, en laravel vamos a usar `npm` para instalar las dependencias

   ```
   npm install
   npm install moment --save
   ```
3. Ahora, como se van a hacer cambios en ficheros `.js` y los queremos reflejar en nuestro proyecto instantáneamente, usamos:

   ```
   npm run watch
   ```
4. Para resolver tu duda puntual voy a omitir código innecesario de el set inicial que trae laravel.

   en el directorio de tu proyecto, en el fichero `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` omitiendo todo el código existente, agregamos la siguiente línea:

   ```
   window.moment = require('moment');
   ```

   esto crea una variable global para acceder a momentjs.
5. agrega el `app.js` al markup del proyecto actual. Puedes hacerlo con:

   ```
   <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
   ```

**Listo, ya tienes momentjs instalado y configurado globalmente**

*Pruebas simples*

1. ingresa a la consola de tu navegador preferido y ejecuta `moment()`. Verás el resultado sin ningún error.

   [image: Ejemplo MomentJs en consola del navegador]
2. Usa Vue js como tu Framework de desarrollo Javascript.

   en el fichero `resources/assets/js/components/app.js/` busca la instancia que trae por defecto laravel y ajusta el código para que se vea como:

   ```
   const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {           
           time: moment().format('Y-M-d H:mm:ss')
       }
   });
   ```

   Donde `time` va a ser un dato de tu instacia Vue.

   En tu markup agrega el identificador `app` a uno de tus elementos, e imprime el dato `time`

   ```
   <div id="app" class="title m-b-md">
       @{{ time }}
   </div>
   ```

Así obtendrás directamente en html el resultado deseado 
[image: Ejemplo MomentJs en vista]

Comment: ¡Perfecto! ¡Funciona! ¡Muchas gracias! Voy a investigar sobre esto, pero la pregunta es, ¿cual es la diferencia entre uno y otro? Ambos deberían de incluir la librería. He tenido que hacer lo mismo con `laroute` si quería meterlo en el `webpack.mix.js`. ¿Podrías ampliar la respuesta con estos datos?

Comment: Te refieres a la diferencia entre `moment` y `moment-with-locale` ?

Comment: No, a la diferencia de hacer un `include('../../..');` y hacer un '`window.moment = require('moment');` porqué de una forma si que funciona y de la otra no, cuando (a mi entender, aunque evidentemente estoy confundido) ambas deberían de incluir la librería.

Comment: Al usar `require('../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js');` estás requiriendo un fichero en tu proyecto, pero justamente como ha sido indicado en varios issues, ejemplo [este](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2979#issuecomment-189232930), hay problemas con algunos archivos relativos a ese archivo y su compatibilidad con webpack. 

Haciendo `require('moment')` estás requiriendo directamente un modulo dentro de 'node_modules' no soy un experto en el tema pero [aquí](https://bytearcher.com/articles/loading_modules_with_require/) hay más información. Espero una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, toda la información adicional la añadiría a la respuesta, para que la persona que se encuentre en la misma situación lo tenga en cuenta. De nuevo, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de reproducir el problema y lo he solventado cambiando:

```
//var moment = require('moment');
require('../../../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');
```

de tu fichero `resources/assets/js/app.js`por:

```
window.moment = require('moment');
```

Después de aplicar `npm run dev` o `npm run watch` de nuevo, la librería ya era accesible desde la consola y era posible cambiar de idioma con la función `locale`:

```
moment().locale('es').format('LLL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos por si aun sirve la solución mas sencilla con esta configuración en tu bootstrap.js o app.js

```
import "moment/locale/es";

window.moment = require("moment");
```

con eso tiene moment como variable global y configurado en español

Answer (score -1):

Tenia el mismo problema, yo estoy usando **`laravel 6`**
El problema es que al momento de ejecutar el comando para instalar **`moment js`**
`npm install moment --save` al parecer si se instala la librería, pero si te vas a la carpeta `node_modules/moment` en donde se supone que estarían los archivos de la librería solo aparece el archivo `package.json.`

Lo que tienes que hacer para solucionar esto es ir al repositorio de **github** de **`momentjs`**

https://github.com/moment/moment/

Y descargar o clonar el repositorio dentro de la carpeta de `node_modules/moment`

Y con esto se soluciona el problema.